# Looping a list of URLs in Python

Tags: python

I have 4 URLs in a list and I want to call the request on each URL and store the JSON data in a list. However these URLs are pages and some pages might be empty.

This is my code:

```
import request
import json

urls = ['https://api.leadfeeder.com/accounts/**leads?1','https://api.leadfeeder.com/accounts/**leads?2','https://api.leadfeeder.com/accounts/**leads?3']

header = {"Authorization": 'Bearer Sn1S***bmjtUEQDX8*****'}

for u in urls:
    resp = requests.get(u, headers = header).json()
    if len(resp['data']) > 0:
        print(resp['data'])
        s=resp['data']
```

The `if` statement is to check the response of the URLs because some page has 0 length.

My issue is when I `print(resp['data'])`, I get all the JSON data of all URLs with length greater than 0, but when I store it in a variable it only stores the last URL I called.

Comment: If you overwrite a variable each iteration, that variable will only have the last value written.

Comment: You're reassigning the variable `s` inside the loop each time, so it loses its value from the previous loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a python dictionary to store your urls response.

```
import request
import json

urls = ['https://api.leadfeeder.com/accounts/**leads? 
1','https://api.leadfeeder.com/accounts/**leads? 
2','https://api.leadfeeder.com/accounts/**leads?3']

header = {"Authorization": 'Bearer Sn1S***bmjtUEQDX8*****'}

response_dict = {}

for u in urls:
   resp = requests.get(u, headers = header).json()
   if len(resp['data']) > 0:
      print(resp['data'])
      response_dict[u] = resp['data']

print(response_dict)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a list or dictionary to store your json data. When you have it printed, it prints each one but overwrites the variable s each time.

```
import request
import json

urls = ['https://api.leadfeeder.com/accounts/**leads?1','https://api.leadfeeder.com/accounts/**leads?2','https://api.leadfeeder.com/accounts/**leads?3']

header = {"Authorization": 'Bearer Sn1S***bmjtUEQDX8*****'}
respdata = []

for u in urls:
    resp = requests.get(u, headers = header).json()
    if len(resp['data']) > 0:
        print(resp['data'])
        respdata.append(resp['data'])
```

alternatively you could use a dictionary to keep the mapping with the urls:

```
import request
import json

urls = ['https://api.leadfeeder.com/accounts/**leads?1','https://api.leadfeeder.com/accounts/**leads?2','https://api.leadfeeder.com/accounts/**leads?3']

header = {"Authorization": 'Bearer Sn1S***bmjtUEQDX8*****'}
respdata = {}

for u in urls:
    resp = requests.get(u, headers = header).json()
    if len(resp['data']) > 0:
        print(resp['data'])
        respdata[u] = resp['data']
```

Answer (score 0):

You are overwritting the `s` variable in every iteration of the `for` loop. That's why after the `for` loop is complete you only have the result of the last iteration stored in the variable `s`. Try appending it on a list as the other answers suggested.

Answer (score 0):

The print is printing one URL’s data. It is being called for each url in your loop. To save all the pages data, add this line Before the loop:

`allData = []`

Then, after your print statement, add this line in the loop:

`allData.append(resp['data'])`

All the pages’ data is now stored in the list allData.